# Report viewer on ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i have an ASP web page has two text-boxes for username and password and the log in button and report-viewer

when the user enter the username and password right (checked by database) the report needed to be shown.

i tried to make the report-viewer visibility is false at first and make it true when the username and password are right but it show the report-viewer with no report

the report must shown at the page load to be right

i want to know two things if i can make what i want right so how>?

and if not how can i tell the button if the username and password right go to another page?

Comment: Sorry, is this asp-classic or asp.net?

Comment: Post your code and maybe someone may spot something that you missed.

Comment: it is asp 2010 asp.net